# Webpack production build fails : "Can't resolve 'aws-sdk'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack

I am writing an Express application in TypeScript and trying to use webpack to transpile both production code and vendor modules into a single bundle.js file. But I can not do so because of a weird node-pre-gyp error :

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in '[...]/harema-api/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
```

I am running node 8.11.2. Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

Any idea ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In my case, the problem was resolved by switching to `bcryptjs` package instead of `bcrypt`. A little bit slower, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I added the package and error has disapeared, however it added 4.5MB (!) to my package.

Deleting the whole 'node_modules' folder and 'npm install' solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still having this problem, I fixed this by explicitly specifying `--config` with the `webpack` command, rather than just using the config as the first argument or omitting it.

Before: `webpack ./webpack.config.js --mode production` // ERROR: Unable to resolve ...

After: `webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode production`

I admit I'm not certain why this addressed the problem as in my case it was reading the config file either way. I'm using webpack v4.16.2 and webpack-cli v3.1.0.

Comment: I switched to it and the error was gone. Thought it is a win but looked in the built file and this was transpiled webpack.config.js. So not a solution.